# Windows messages and their deterministic properties

Tags: windows, message-queue

I'd like to confirm what I think to be true.  When I use Windows `SendMessage()`, this is a deterministic call in that it will execute immediately (will not return until the message is processed) as opposed to `PostMessage()` which is non-deterministic as it can be preempted by any other message that happens to be in the queue at that moment in time (in fact it will not be executed until it hits the message loop).

Is this a fair assessment, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That is essentially true for in-process calls. Cross-process SendMessage works similar, but processing of the message doesn't begin until the receiver process calls GetMessage (or its kin).

Your UI thread has a message pump that looks something like:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg))
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
```

PostMessage causes the message to be put onto the message queue. GetMessage removes the oldest message from the queue (FIFO*).

DispatchMessage causes the WndProc associated with the message's target window to be called with the message.

SendMessage basically bypasses this chain and calls the WndProc directly (more or less).

A lot of standard window messages result in a chain of SendMessage calls where sending one message sends another which sends another. That chain is often referred to as "the current dispatch". If you need your message to be processed inside the chain, use SendMessage. If you need it to be processed after the current dispatch has completed, use PostMessage.

You can use a tool like [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx) to see Windows messaging in action, or to debug problems you're having with message order of operations.

[*] It's not strictly a FIFO queue because certain kinds of messages (i.e. timer, mouse, keyboard) are not actually posted to the queue, but rather generated on the fly. For the sake of simplicity, you can think of it as a FIFO.